# How to get excel file in .net core web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I already have created a project in the .net web API 2.2 version framework which gets an excel file from the angular framework. Now, I wanted to explore this project to understand the **.net core** better. I have added the angular service file code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  url = "https://localhost:44339";

  UploadExcel(formdata: FormData){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept','application/json');

    const httpOptions = {headers: headers};

    return this.http.post(this.url+'/ExcelExample',formdata,httpOptions);

  }

  BindUser():Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.url+'/UserDetails');
  }
}
```

And the component.ts file which calls the above service API methods:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../model/user';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-excelimport',
  templateUrl: './excelimport.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./excelimport.component.scss']
})
export class ExcelimportComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput:any;
  message:String|undefined;
  allUsers:Observable<User[]>|undefined;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllUser();
  }

  loadAllUser(){
    this.allUsers=this.service.BindUser();
  }

  uploadFile(){
    let formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0])

    this.service.UploadExcel(formData).subscribe(result=>{
      this.message=result.toString();
      this.loadAllUser();
    });
  }

}
```

Do you have the .net core framework code which gets the above excel file and update the data to SQL Server Database (using Stored Procedures will help me a lot)?
My SQL DB table design is as follows:

[SQL DB table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAxNP.png)

**EDIT**:
I have added how I got an excel file in the web API .net framework:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Index()
        {
            string message = "";
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;
            var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
            using (ShubhamPractiseEntities1 objEntity = new ShubhamPractiseEntities1())
            {

                if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = httpRequest.Files[0];
                    Stream stream = file.InputStream;

                    IExcelDataReader reader = null;

                    if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                    }
                    else if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "This file format is not supported";
                    }

                    DataSet excelRecords = reader.AsDataSet();
                    reader.Close();

                    var finalRecords = excelRecords.Tables[0];
                    for (int i = 0; i < finalRecords.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        UserDetail objUser = new UserDetail();
                        objUser.UserName = finalRecords.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                        objUser.EmailId = finalRecords.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        objUser.Gender = finalRecords.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                        objUser.Address = finalRecords.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                        objUser.MobileNo = finalRecords.Rows[i][4].ToString();
                        objUser.PinCode = finalRecords.Rows[i][5].ToString();

                        objEntity.UserDetails.Add(objUser);

                    }

                    int output = objEntity.SaveChanges();
                    if (output > 0)
                    {
                        message = "Excel file has been successfully uploaded";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Excel file uploaded has fiald";
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
            }
            return message;
        }
```

I wanted this in the .net core framework. Please help.

Comment: This code doesn't help. You want to upload an Excel file and import it to a database. What stack are you actually using? ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET Core are different. [This shows how to handle uploading in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - create an action that accepts a `List<IFormFile>` parameter

Comment: Thank you, but this List<IFormFile> will be created in Angular. It will really help me if you help me get the documentation for creating such a method.

Comment: I already posted the link. This has nothing to do with Angular, the linked code shows how to handle file uploads sent using an `input type=file`. It doesn't matter if you use Angular or a plain old `<form>` with file input to upload files, the HTTP request should be the same. To handle the files, you need to receive them as `IFormFile`

Comment: BTW ORMs like EF Core are **not** built for bulk imports and ETL. Since you use ExcelDataReader, you can pass the DbDataReader instance to `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` to insert the data into a table directly